# Incorrect encoding in Python 3 for Windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, encoding

I'm trying to open a csv file with Python for Windows (v3.7, from Microsoft Store).
This file has cyrillic symbols in name and in first row (used as table header).
But somehow Python cannot find the file.

#### Problem #1

I'm trying to find what's wrong using this code:

```
filepath = os.path.join(files_path, filename)
print("filepath is: ", filepath)
print(os.listdir(files_path))
if not os.path.isfile(filepath):
    raise FileNotFoundError('No file {}'.format(filename))
```

Then, I get this output (stack trace contains no valuable info, so i don't post it here)

```
filepath is:  C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\data-loader\files\Москва_Год_2013_Неделя_4 — копия.csv
['������_���_2013_������_4 � �����.csv']
FileNotFoundError: No file Москва_Год_2013_Неделя_4 — копия.csv
```

### Problem #2

I'm trying to open this file using pandas after renaming it to all-latin characters.
The file is semicolon-delimited text file. Example below:

```
ID транзакции;Дата;ID товара;ID магазина;Количество
1;41624;38;1;1
2;41624;35;1;1
3;41624;27;1;1
```

The file can be read, but when i try to pick a column from it, i get a KeyError.
The code (with my debug attempts) below:

```
with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:  # I know it's wrong.
   dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiters=";,")
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding="utf-8", dialect=dialect)
print(list(df.columns))
ser = df[file_key]  # Дата, in my case.
```

The output is:

```
['ID ����������', '����', 'ID ������', 'ID ��������', '����������']

 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\realg\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.7_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 2891, in get_loc
     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
   File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 101, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1675, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
   File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1683, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Дата'
```

If i replace cyrillic characters in column names to latin ones, then my code works ok.
On Python for Linux, everything is ok either.

So the question is how can i get rid of these errors?

### Update

Following @SergeyBushmanov comment, i've tried to solve problem #2 by using `chardet` module like this:

```
with open(filepath, 'rb') as csvfile:
    file_encoding = chardet.detect(csvfile.read())
with open(filepath, 'r') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read(1024), delimiters=";,")
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, encoding=file_encoding['encoding'], dialect=dialect)
```

But nothing changed.

Comment: Start with determining what is encoding for your file. `Chardet` may be helpful here. After that most probably you'll need to convert file to the encoding your Windows machine understands.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov but what about file name? I can't even open a file with cyrillic symbols in its name.

Comment: This is a good question. Anyways, my understanding is still the same: this is encoding related question. What really bothers me, your file is most probably is `utf8` encoded (it reads well on Linux). But even after specifying the most probable encoding contents are still not displayed correctly. Confirm the file encoding is `utf8`, find why it's not displayed correclt, and you'll most probably know why file name is not picked up either

Comment: Yup, the file encoding is utf8. I've tried to follow your first comment, but it didn't help.

Comment: You can be more spcific in titling your question like "Windows cant read utf8 encoded file names". There are some related threads can be found on google and SO with answers